# ng-table filter not filtering all pages

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I am working on angular application where I am using `ng-table` for grid functionality but there are two issues I am facing.

1. Filter option is searching for current page data not searching all pages
2. total count displaying wrong count ans its in decimal

Here is screen shot

[image]

JS file is as below :

```
app.controller('AllJobListController', function 
($scope, $http, $location, $filter, NgTableParams, jobService, ShareData, $sce) {
    loadAllJobRecords();
    GetFilterData();
    function GetFilterData() {
        var promiseFilterData = jobService.GetFilterData();
        promiseFilterData.then(function(pl) {
            $scope.FilterData = pl.data;
        });
    }

    $scope.viewFilter = function () {
        $scope.filters = {
            Staff: $scope.FilterData.Staff == undefined ? null : $scope.FilterData.Staff,
            Priority: $scope.FilterData.Priority == undefined ? null : $scope.FilterData.Priority,
            Manager: $scope.FilterData.Manager == undefined ? null : $scope.FilterData.Manager,
            Status: $scope.FilterData.Status == undefined ? null : $scope.FilterData.Status
        }
        $scope.tableParams.filter($scope.filters);

    };

        $scope.search = '';

    function loadAllJobRecords() {
        $("#divLoading").show();
        var promiseGetAllJobs = jobService.GetAllJobs();
        promiseGetAllJobs.then(function (pl) {
            $("#divLoading").hide();
            $scope.Jobs = pl.data;
            $scope.JobTitle = "All Engagements";
            $scope.Action = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("/Job/ExportAllJobRecords");
            //  $scope.Action = "/Job/ExportAllJobRecords";
            $scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({
                page: 1,              // show first page
                count: 10,             // count per page
                sorting: {
                    JobNum: 'asc' // initial sorting
                },
                filter: $scope.search

            },
                { dataset: pl.data },
                {
                    total: pl.data.length,
                    getData: function ($defer, params) {
                        var filteredData = params.filter() ? $filter('filter')(pl.data, params.filter()) : pl.data;
                        var orderedData = params.sorting() ? $filter('orderBy')(filteredData, params.orderBy()) : filteredData; params.total(filteredData.length);
                        $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
                    }
                });
        },
              function (errorPl) {
                  $scope.error = errorPl;
              });
    }

});
```

And Html is as below

```
<div class="x_panel">
    <div class="x_title">
        <h2>{{JobTitle}}<small></small></h2>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="x_content col-md-12">

        <div class="row col-md-12 data-tablex">       

            <div class="col-md-offset-8 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12  data-tablex data-tabley">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" ng-model="search" />
            </div>

        <div class="col-md-offset-8 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12  data-tablex data-tableym">                 
                    <form action="{{Action}}" method="post" class="frm-export" id="frmexport">
                    @{Html.RenderAction("Filter", "Job");}      
            <input type="submit" value="Export" class="btn-export" id="btnexport" />

                <a href="" class="toggle-filter"><i class="fa fa-list"></i> Filter</a>

            <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('btnexport').click();"><i class="fa fa-list"></i> Export</a>

                    @*  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="Export(Jobs)">Export</button>*@
        </form>
            </div>

        <div class="col-md-offset-8 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12  data-tablex data-tableyr">
                 <p class="text-right">
                    <strong>page: {{tableParams.page()}} of {{tableParams.total()/tableParams.count()}}</strong>
                </p>
            </div>

    <div class="form-group form-filter">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-0 row table-filter">
        <form action="{{Action}}" method="post" class="frm-exportx">
                    @{Html.RenderAction("Filter", "Job");}      
           </form>               
            </div>
        </div>


            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 colxs12  data-tablex" style="">
                <table id="tblAllJobs" class="ng-table-responsive table table-striped table-bordered table-jobs" ng-table="tableParams" template-pagination="custom/pager">
                    <tr ng-repeat="Job in $data | filter:search">
                        <td data-title="'Job'" sortable="'JobNum'">
                            <a href="/#/EditJob" ng-click="editJob(Job.JobNum)">{{ Job.JobNum }}</a>
                        </td>
                        <td data-title="'Priority'" sortable="'Priority'">
                            {{ Job.Priority }}
                        </td>
                        <td data-title="'Staff'" sortable="'Staff'">
                            {{ Job.Staff }}
                        </td>
                        <td data-title="'Title'" sortable="'JobName'">
                            {{ Job.JobName }}
                        </td>
                        <td data-title="'Company'" sortable="'Company'">
                            {{ Job.Company}}
                        </td>
                        <td data-title="'Deadlines'" sortable="'Deadlines'">
                            {{ Job.Deadlines}}
                        </td>
                        <td data-title="'Status'" sortable="'StatusComment'">
                            {{ Job.StatusComment}}
                        </td>
                        <td data-title="'Copy'" class="td-center"><a href="/#/CreateAsNewJob" ng-click="CreateAsNewJob(Job.JobNum)"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></td>
                        @* <td data-title="'Edit'"><a ng-click="editJob(Job.JobNum)"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a></td>*@
                    </tr>
                    @*  <tr class="noRecordMsg" ng-hide="$data.length"><td colspan="7" align="center">No Jobs available</td></tr>*@
                    <tr class="noRecordMsg" ng-hide="$data.length"><td colspan="8" align="center">No Jobs available</td></tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="custom/pager">
    <ul class="pager ng-cloak">
        <li ng-repeat="page in pages"
            ng-class="{'disabled': !page.active, 'previous': page.type == 'prev', 'next': page.type == 'next'}"
            ng-show="page.type == 'prev' || page.type == 'next'" ng-switch="page.type">
            <a ng-switch-when="prev" ng-click="params.page(page.number)" href="">&laquo; Previous</a>
            <a ng-switch-when="next" ng-click="params.page(page.number)" href="">Next &raquo;</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" ng-class="{'active':params.count() == 5}" ng-click="params.count(5)" class="btn btn-default">5</button>
                <button type="button" ng-class="{'active':params.count() == 10}" ng-click="params.count(10)" class="btn btn-default">10</button>
                <button type="button" ng-class="{'active':params.count() == 20}" ng-click="params.count(20)" class="btn btn-default">20</button>
                <button type="button" ng-class="{'active':params.count() == 50}" ng-click="params.count(50)" class="btn btn-default">50</button>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</script>
```

I have searched for filter issue but couldn't find solution to that.